# DateTime and DateFormat suddenly not working in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime, format

I am trying to create a quote page where you can view the posts you post with the author, quote and date.

Let me rephrase this. When I try to add a new entry into the database using the php page, it enters it into the database as: 
0000-00-00 00:00:00

when it should enter that moment's date and time.

Here is my code snippet. 
...echoing the date in the view post page code.

```
echo $date_entered = date("F d,Y", strtotime($row['date_entered']));
```

...inserting the new entry into the database page code...
    $sql  ="INSERT INTO quotes  (author, quote, date_entered) VALUES ('$author', '$quote', '$date_entered')";

This is my form code:

```
<body>
    <form action=""add_quote.php method="post" enctype="multi-part/form-data">
        <input placeholder="Author" name="author" type="text" autofocus size="48"><br /><br />
        <textarea placeholder="Quote" name="quote" rows="20" cols="50"></textarea><br />
        <input name="post" type="submit" value="Add Quote">
    </form>

</body>
```

I have searched on here for any answers as well as googled and bing'd it to no luck. Please Help!

Comment: well, what's in `$row['date']`?

Comment: The date format has to be `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` in order to store it into a DATETIME MySQL column

Comment: Even when I enter it in PHPmyadmin it doesnt give me a date and time....I have tried different codes and it all gives me the same result...0.Could it be my computer?

Comment: please show your table definition and what you 'enter in PHPmyAdmin'.

Comment: **Unless you tell us what is in `$row['date']` we cannot give you a complete and accurate answer**

Comment: it is assigned the date_entered variable to match the database table column

Comment: Also. I just added it to another page instead, and it does format it...but the date has seemed to be reset. January 1 1970

Comment: **NO** Show us an actual example

Comment: `January 1 1970` is the default when **the date is being entered to MYSQL IN THE WRONG FORMAT**

Comment: what do yoj mean show you an example?

Comment: and dont yell please. I am new to PHP

Comment: do an `echo $row['date'];` and show us what is printed

Comment: But you are not listening to the requests for more and more importantly **more accurate** information

Comment: this __could__ work, depending of what's in $row: `$date_entered = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($row['date']));` (just formatting to a mysql valid datetime, as RiggsFolly insited)

Comment: 2018-04-13 18:46:01

Comment: Then it does NOT need changing in any way at all. leave it as it is. THAT is a valid format while `April 13,2018` is totally invalid

Comment: but when I try to enter a new entry/post it gives me all 0

Comment: if that's in $row['date'] already, then there's no need for the transformation... just put it into db

Comment: If you just want the DATE part of that DateTime then use `date("Y-m-d",strtotime($row['date']));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use like below,

```
$d = new DateTime($row['date_entered']);
$date_entered = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
$sql = "INSERT INTO quotes  (author, quote, date_entered) VALUES ('$author', '$quote', '$date_entered')";
```

mysql `DATETIME` type column format should be : `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

Comment: that's a bit too much cross-formatting, don't you think?

Comment: Jezz I gota concur with @Jeff on this ine

Comment: Seems to me like `$date_entered = $d->format('Y-m-d')` would do what was required here

Comment: PS: The OP finally told us that the date string they are dealing with is `2018-04-13 18:46:01` which in fact need no fiddling at all

Comment: we dont know what's in `$row['date']`, codes seem like user submitting the date and he needs to store in database, before store he should format it.

Comment: @user4839691 try my answer

Comment: That worked it seems, so to try to understand this, it was because I had the format wrong? Thanks everyone for working with me despite my lack of information! I am trying to get better at describing things and my terminology

Comment: Yes, the format that you put into database was wrong, but your original format would have been right. So this is __a lot__ of overhead.

Comment: Thank you RiggsFolly and Jeff and Anfath

Comment: `$sql = "INSERT INTO quotes  (author, quote, date_entered) VALUES ('$author', '$quote', '{$row['date_entered']}')";` would also work. without the two lines before. Just sayin...

Answer (score 1):

Here's the shorthand:
If you are sure that `$row['date_entered']` will be in format `2018-04-13 18:46:01`, as you've stated, you can simply do

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO quotes (author, quote, date_entered) VALUES ('$author', '$quote', '{$row['date_entered']}')";
```

without any re-formatting.

If you wanna make sure do the short reformatting:

```
$date_entered = new DateTime($row['date_entered'])->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');   
$sql = "INSERT INTO quotes  (author, quote, date_entered) VALUES ('$author', '$quote', '$date_entered')";
```

Comment: There is no justice sometimes :( so have a +1

Comment: thanks for that. sometimes we have the right answer as first comment (like __you__ here, this should have been your answer) but it just doesn't get picked up. So I just wanted to add it for completeness.

Comment: I am not bothered, I was more upset that the other answer got upvoted and accepted when its so obviously nonsense